# Messed with DNS, now does not connect to Internet

Tags: wireless, networking, dns

So I was trying to fix this reverse DNS issue:

```
$ dig HOSTNAME.DOMAIN.com
1.2.3.4                  #example

$ dig -x 1.2.3.4
OTHERHOSTNAME.OTHERDOMAIN.com
```

I was blindly following online instructions to fix it:

In, `/etc/hosts`,
I changed the first line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

to

```
127.0.0.1 HOSTNAME.DOMAIN.com localhost.localdomain localhost
```

then I did:

```
sudo /sbin/dhclient -r
```

I believe by then I realized I no longer had internet connection, even though I was still connected to WiFi.  I reverted the edit to `/etc/hosts`, without effect.

(I am posting from another computer, so first I would like to fix the internet connection on original computer).

Any ideas?  Thanks

EDIT:
@Alaa ali 's initial proposal didn't work for me, but he told me to restart my machine, which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo /sbin/dhclient -r` releases (`-r`) the IP address obtained from your DHCP server. That is what caused your connection to drop, since now your machine does not have an IP address to communicate to the network.

To fix this issue, you should simply request a new IP address. But first, we'll make sure that it is released by executing this command:

```
sudo /sbin/dhclient -r wlan0
```

Then to request a new one from your DHCP server, simply do:

```
sudo /sbin/dhclient wlan0
```

(Assuming that your wireless interface is called `wlan0`. If it isn't, take a look at the output of `iwconfig` and find out the name of the entry that has wireless information next to it).

That command should complete fairly quickly and you'll see that an IP address has been assigned to your interface. Now try browsing the internet.

Comment: The output was `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`.  Still no internet connection.  I think `wlan0` was the right interface, since it had my WiFi SSID next to it.

Comment: @onepiece Hmm, alright try `sudo dhclient -r wlan0` then `sudo dhclient wlan0`.

Comment: Still no connection :(.  Both commands finished without any output

Comment: [Let's take this to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16965/messed-with-dns-now-does-not-connect-to-internet).